# Does a firewall TCP timeout require a TLS resume?

Tags: ssl, tcp

A firewall is timing out TCP connections after an hour.

Sending a message along this connection from the server results in a [RST, ACK] from the firewall. 
[image]

Messages sent from the client are simply dropped, as long as they are part of the original connection.
[image]

If a new connection is established from the client, it goes through the firewall without a hitch.

This is normal - routers, firewalls, VPNs, NATs, etc.., all time out connections and require you to reconnect with a new handshake or perform a TLS resume. But is there any way to continue using the TLS session without "resuming" it? I say this because the TLS session never ended, only the underlying TCP.

Because the TLS session is independent of TCP, we shouldn't need to resume an already active TLS session just because some intermediary device blocks us. Is there any type of "TCP resume" that we can do along the same socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "session resumption" in TLS.

Quoting the latest standard on it (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446) :

> Although TLS PSKs can be established out of band, PSKs can also be
> established in a previous connection and then used to establish a new
> connection ("session resumption" or "resuming" with a PSK).  Once a
> handshake has completed, the server can send the client a PSK
> identity that corresponds to a unique key derived from the initial
> handshake (see Section 4.6.1).  The client can then use that PSK
> identity in future handshakes to negotiate the use of the associated
> PSK.  If the server accepts the PSK, then the security context of the
> new connection is cryptographically tied to the original connection
> and the key derived from the initial handshake is used to bootstrap
> the cryptographic state instead of a full handshake.  In TLS 1.2 and
> below, this functionality was provided by "session IDs" and "session
> tickets" [RFC5077].  Both mechanisms are obsoleted in TLS 1.3.

See sections 2.2 and 4.6.1 of the RFC for details.

It can not be a resumption at the TCP level since the new TCP connection will need to start with a new local port (otherwise any traffic will still be caught by firewall state tracking).

Comment: So the firewall keeps track of the old TCP connection and it won't let any TCP communications in from that outbound port ?

Comment: Is there no way around having to reuse a session? This resumption takes time and it's odd that a firewall could just say "you have to resume". Using UDP, you wouldn't have this issue

Comment: If it maintains state the state is based on this 4 items tuple: source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port. Depending on the firewall, but if nothing changes in the tuple it will apply the same result that is breaking the connection at least during some time.

Comment: Note that all your problems come only from this: "A firewall is timing out TCP connections after an hour. " so whatever solutions you are attempting to use are just for going around this firewall configuration. Saying otherwise: get rid of this firewall (or at least this specific rule), or configure it differently if it messes up your setup. Note also that you have keepalives both at the TCP layer and at application layers (for example in ssh). They may, depending on the firewall, help maintaining the connection open.

Comment: The firewall timing out the connections is not configurable by us - it is somewhere between our server side network and the client's network. And for that matter, we can't be sure that it is a Firewall or NAT or something else.